# jquery postback using c# and asp.net returns null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

I am attempting to use jquery to call a c# function when a button is clicked. What happens is the return variable (msg) is null.

The button code:

```
    <button id="test1" runat="server">Get Text</button>
```

The JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#test1").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ServiceDirectoryAdd.aspx/GetCurrentDate",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });


        });

    });
```

The C# function:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentDate()
    {

        return "foo";
    }
```

As I said, the return variable, msg, returns null. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: After placing a breakpoint in the C# function, it seems that the program is not entering the function.

Comment: is msg returning `null` or `[Object] object` ?

Also,from what i've seen, Ive always found data from webmethod lying in `msg.d`, not just in `msg`. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: As soon as you begin troubleshooting Ajax requests, you're going to want to learn how to use one of the tools that shows the details of your request and response. Check out [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or Postman, which is a Chrome plugin.

Comment: msg is returning null not [Object] object. If one attempts to use msg.d, an error appears in Chrome's debug mode saying it can't get property d from null.

Comment: Did u try putting a breakpoint inside the web method to see if the control actually steps into it?

Comment: PassionateCoder, thank you for your suggestion. It seems that the control does not actually step into the function.

Comment: please add an error option to the `ajax` call. and give us the output so that it'll be easier for ppl to understand. or, chrome dev tools can also help. add this error option :

`error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }`

Comment: The alert box still only says null. Therefore, I'm assuming that it is still entering the success function for some reason.

Comment: i set this up in my computer and this seems to work for me :(

Comment: Since it seems that the C# function isn't being called, but the jquery code is working, could it have something to to with the location of my function? It is located in ServiceDirectoryAdd.aspx.cs

Comment: @cruskai239 can you remove the `runat=server` and try?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30858/discussion-between-passionatecoder-and-cruskai239)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added script manager to page. If you not added it. Please add it and then script manager "EnablePageMethod" property to true.

Here is the link for that.
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: It's set to true. Still returning null. The tutorial you sent was the tutorial I am attempting to follow.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question or not, but when viewing the source in Chrome's developer mode, I can see the jquery function that I posted above.

Comment: I am talking about page method code not the jquery code do view source and find pagemethod

Comment: Which .Net version you are using? I think there is a problem with Page Method creation and that's why its not loading that.

Comment: I am using .Net Version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `GET`?

```
$.get("ServiceDirectoryAdd.aspx/GetCurrentDate", function(data){
    alert(data || data.d);
});
```

And edit the `webmethod` to accept `get`

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public static string GetCurrentDate()
{

    return "foo";
}
```

Comment: Allowing get still returns null.

Comment: Your JQuery code returns undefined with data.d and a blank alert with data.

Comment: I'll get a working sample up tomorrow. I did a few ASMX services back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

try with indexing the msg

```
alert(msg[0]); or  alert(msg.d);
```